# Mysql Sort Like Table of Contents

Tags: mysql, sql

I need make ordering like table of contents order by parent recursive

- -1
- -1.1
- --1.1.1
- -1.2
- -2
- -2.1
- 3

I have stack at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76c71f/1

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Order by name should give you the expected result:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN parent = 0 THEN id ELSE parent END AS sort FROM article_category 
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood:-

you should order your column name to

```
SELECT * FROM article_category
ORDER BY NAME
```

**UPDATE:** [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76c71f/21/0)

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN parent = 0 THEN id ELSE parent END) AS sort FROM article_category 
ORDER BY  name, sort, id
```

Comment: You can remove `id` if you want to sort it with `name` and `sort` - *"maybe this is what you want to do, because you create a new column `sort` that can adapt the value of parent and replace the value of parent where the value is 0 by its current id"*